# Pycairo build failed as I tried upload django project to Railway

Tags: python, django, railway

I have been trying to upload my django project to Railway but whenever i try to upload fro my github repo this is the stack error i get

```
﻿
#10 27.27             copying cairo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cairo
﻿
#10 27.27             copying cairo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cairo
﻿
#10 27.27             copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/cairo
﻿
#10 27.27             running build_ext
﻿
#10 27.27             Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
﻿
#10 27.27             Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
﻿
#10 27.27             to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
﻿
#10 27.27             No package 'cairo' found
﻿
#10 27.27             Command '['pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'cairo >= 1.15.10']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
﻿
#10 27.27             [end of output]
﻿
#10 27.27
﻿
#10 27.27         note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
﻿
#10 27.27         ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycairo
﻿
#10 27.27       Failed to build pycairo
﻿
#10 27.27       ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycairo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
﻿
#10 27.27
﻿
#10 27.27       [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.2.1
﻿
#10 27.27       [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
﻿
#10 27.27       [end of output]
﻿
#10 27.27
﻿
#10 27.27   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
﻿
 
﻿
#10 27.27 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
﻿
#10 27.27
﻿
#10 27.27 × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
﻿
#10 27.27 │ exit code: 1
﻿
#10 27.27 ╰─> See above for output.
﻿
#10 27.27
﻿
#10 27.27 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
﻿
#10 27.28
﻿
#10 27.28 [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.2.1
﻿
#10 27.28 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
﻿
 
﻿
#10 ERROR: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c python -m venv --copies /opt/venv && . /opt/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
﻿
-----
﻿
> [stage-0 6/8] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/70360f50-34a1-43ac-906f-e433bf4a1b23-/root/cache/pip,target=/root/.cache/pip python -m venv --copies /opt/venv && . /opt/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt:
﻿
27.27 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
﻿
27.27
﻿
27.27 × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
﻿
27.27 │ exit code: 1
﻿
27.27 ╰─> See above for output.
﻿
27.27
﻿
27.27 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
﻿
27.28
﻿
27.28 [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.2.1
﻿
27.28 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
﻿
-----
﻿
 
﻿
Dockerfile:20
﻿
-------------------
﻿
18 |     ENV NIXPACKS_PATH /opt/venv/bin:$NIXPACKS_PATH
﻿
19 |     COPY . /app/.
﻿
20 | >>> RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/70360f50-34a1-43ac-906f-e433bf4a1b23-/root/cache/pip,target=/root/.cache/pip python -m venv --copies /opt/venv && . /opt/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt
﻿
21 |
﻿
22 |
﻿
-------------------
﻿
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c python -m venv --copies /opt/venv && . /opt/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
﻿
 
﻿
Error: Docker build failed
﻿
```

this is my requirements.txt file

```
reportlab==3.6.8
asgiref==3.6.0
bcrypt==3.2.0
blinker==1.4
bootstrap4==0.1.0
certifi==2020.6.20
crispy-bootstrap4==2022.1
cryptography==3.4.8
dbus-python==1.2.18
Django==4.2
django-crispy-forms==2.0
django-extensions==3.2.3
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.8
gunicorn==21.2.0
httplib2==0.20.2
importlib-metadata==4.6.4
jeepney==0.7.1
launchpadlib==1.10.16
lazr.restfulclient==0.14.4
lazr.uri==1.0.6
lockfile==0.12.2
macaroonbakery==1.3.1
Mako==1.1.3
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
monotonic==1.6
more-itertools==8.10.0
netifaces==0.11.0
oauthlib==3.2.0
olefile==0.46
packaging==23.1
paramiko==2.9.3
pexpect==4.8.0
Pillow==9.0.1
protobuf==3.12.4
psycopg2-binary==2.9.7
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pycups==2.0.1
Pygments==2.11.2
PyGObject==3.42.1
PyJWT==2.3.0
pymacaroons==0.13.0
PyNaCl==1.5.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyRFC3339==1.1
python-apt==2.4.0+ubuntu1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-debian===0.1.43ubuntu1
python-decouple==3.8
pytz==2020.1
pyxdg==0.27
PyYAML==5.4.1
requests==2.25.1
SecretStorage==3.3.1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
systemd-python==234
ubuntu-advantage-tools==8001
ubuntu-drivers-common==0.0.0
urllib3==1.26.5
```

i have reinstalled pycairo and am using Ubuntu 22.04. I have re tried with everything online but to no avail. Is possible for me to do this on other Operating system like a windows after i install python and django. The error is also thrown in Railway